# Php - order the current data without reloading the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Im new to web development. I want to know if there is any possible way to order current data(MySQL) on my page without reloading the page.

First i show all data in table as below.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Describe</th>
    <th>Date <a  href="#"><span name="order" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a></th>
 </tr>

<?php
 include 'connect.php';
 global $conn;

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM event";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
 // output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['data'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
 }
} 
else 
{
 echo "0 results";
}
```

I want to fix, when i click in "Data -on that span with glyphicon" to order data immediately without refreshing the page

I tried this, but not working

```js
if(isset($_GET['order']))
  {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY date ASC";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
     {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['data'].'</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
    }
       } 
  }
```

Comment: Your option is JavaScript (either by making AJAX calls to the back-end to refresh data or by using a sorting library like datatables)

Comment: Why don't you just order it from the beginning ? ORDER BY data but what is data exactly?

Comment: @clearshot66 i forgot to translate from my language ,, ORDER BY data =  ORDER BY date

Comment: gotcha.   So what is it doing when you use ORDER BY date ?  What do the dates in your database look like?

Comment: @clearshot66  In MySQL data - varchar(45),, In html  <input type="date">.. And the results are like: 2017-05-18

Comment: @clearshot66 It works well if i order from the beginning.. So i think I will just let this way. Its just a college project :P

Comment: ORDER BY ASC/DESC can change the order as well

Answer (score -1):

You need to use javascript. PHP is a server side language and it's job isn't to do client side work.